# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI, even though there is annotation

Tags: java, spring

My Code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/register")
public class RegisterController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String viewRegistration(Map<String, Object> model) {
        User userForm = new User();    
        model.put("userForm", userForm);

        List<String> professionList = new ArrayList<>();
        professionList.add("Developer");
        professionList.add("Designer");
        professionList.add("IT Manager");
        model.put("professionList", professionList);

        return "Registration";
        }
    }
```

The error I am getting:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringSecurity/register] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Where on the other class I have a code like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView adminPage() {

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    model.addObject("title", "Spring Security Login Form - Database Authentication");
    model.addObject("message", "This page is for ROLE_ADMIN only!");
    model.setViewName("admin");

    return model;

}
```

and it works.

I know it's a little different approach, but what is so different that it doesn't work?

Comment: Can you try to annotate your viewRegistration Map param with `@RequestParam`? (`Map<String, Object> model` to `@RequestParam Map<String, Object> model`)

Comment: Thanks, but didn't help ;/.

Comment: Hello, could you post your dispatcher servlet?

Comment: I have no such thing. I have only controllers with annotations...

Answer (score 0):

I just had to put it into the correct package.

I had an app config with this line:

```
@ComponentScan({ "org.maguss.*" })
```

That defines what packages should spring look into. Since I had my `Controller` in a different package, it wasn't taken into account.